# css: many sibling selectors on the same line

Tags: css, stylesheet, css-selectors, siblings

In my stilesheet I have something similar of what follows:

```
h2.foo1 ~ p.bar1 {
...
} 
h2.foo2 ~ p.bar2 {
...
} 
h2.foo3 ~ p.bar3 {
...
}
```

Since the properties defined within brackets are the same for all, can I combine the above lines in only one, and how? That is, something similar to:

```
h2.foo1 ~ p.bar1 (?) h2.foo2 ~ p.bar2 (?) h2.foo3 ~ p.bar3(?) {
... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma.

```
h2.foo1 ~ p.bar1, h2.foo2 ~ p.bar2, h2.foo3 ~ p.bar3 {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
h2.foo1 ~ p.bar1, h2.foo2 ~ p.bar2, h2.foo3 ~ p.bar3 {
... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, two replies in the same moment, I have chosen which to accept by random...